# How can i make a one time route using Express (node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I tried to to that with a random generated string but the route was not created.

Comment: Can you be more clear on your needs? Do you need a URL that works only once? is that it?

Comment: Yes, I  need a URL that works only once

Comment: can you be bit more clear? what exactly you want to be done ?

Comment: I want to create an auto generated route that once someone used it it will get removed

Comment: @PSYX I understand you are new in the community, so please, if the answer was of any help, accept the answer. This helps the community to keep responding to questions.

Answer (score 1):

The snippet below gives you an idea on how it can be implemented with temporary token. Basically you need to use a path param as a token, verify if that token exists and then discard it after first usage. You can test this code with:
http://localhost:3000/temporary-link/d5407341-3a54-4e30-acf1-09d2174b3e23
After hitting it a second time, it won't work.

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

//get from database or something like it
const allowedUUIDs = ['d5407341-3a54-4e30-acf1-09d2174b3e23',
              '7811c8bf-ddf7-4439-a193-93dca12a0656',  
              'cef82390-9c0a-43e9-93e8-1a80aa5eced5',
              '86520485-9d09-48ba-b65c-9bab0ff2e3a2'
            ];

//test your UUID (access token)
function checkSingleAccess(requestUUID) {
  const index = allowedUUIDs.indexOf(requestUUID);
  const UUIDExists = index > -1;

  if(UUIDExists){
    //remove from array, or your database
    allowedUUIDs.splice(index, 1);
  }

  console.log(UUIDExists);

  return UUIDExists;
}

//set a path parameter with :uuid
app.use('/temporary-link/:uuid', function(req, res, next) {
  //get your path parameter
  const requestUUID = req.params.uuid;

  //test if allowed
  if(checkSingleAccess(requestUUID)){
    res.send(`UUID ${requestUUID} allowed` );
  }else{
    //if not build an error
    const errorResponse = `UUID ${requestUUID} not allowed`;
    res.status(403, errorResponse);
    res.send(errorResponse);
  }
});

module.exports = app;
```